# How to modify url in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to map a url '/admin/update_admin/1' but my url maps to '/admin/1/update_admin' for the provided resources

```
resources :admin
  member do
    post :update_admin
  end
end
```

How to get the expected url? Because of wrong url I am getting the error

```
The action '1' could not be found for AdminController
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want such url - you should try to use collection instead:

```
resources :admin
 collection do
  match "update_admin/:id" => "admin#update_admin", :via => :post
 end
end
```

I am not sure for correct syntax (You can look it here: [Routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html))

Hope it will help you.